# Axios get one parameter with multiple values separated by comma

Tags: javascript, api, axios, query-string

I have a table in React with data about tests which I get from API. I have to do filters on frontend and be able to join them, for example filter tests from chosen category, chosen difficulty and created before some data.

If I wanted to filter for example tests from category "Javascript" and difficulty "Junior", I should get the uri:

/api/admin/filters?filter=category:Javascript,difficulty:JUNIOR

If I wanted to filter tests for "Junior" or "Mid" I should get:

/api/admin/filters?filter=difficulty:JUNIOR,difficulty:'MID
Note apostrophe here which stands for "or".

I should also be able to filter by creation date, for example:

/api/admin/filters?filter=creationDate<2019-09-23 17:34:21,creationDate>2019-09-12 17:34:21

I wonder how I can create such queries? URLSearchParams or axios `params` adds parameters separated by & so I can't use it here because I have one parameter "filter" with multiple values. Or maybe I should use it and also use js replace method for replacing & for comma? I have also no idea how to add apostrophe.

I saw similar question here: https://spectrum.chat/react/general/query-string-sending-multiple-value-to-the-same-parameter~5d029da0-e7da-443d-a4b2-1529ca7b4f82
but I can't use an array in my case because I have multiple filters. I suppose I have to create object like:

```
options = {
     difficulty: [junior, mid],
     category: [javascript],
     created before: 2019-09-23 17:34:21,
     created after: 2019-09-12 17:34:21
}
```

and now how to add keys and values from such object to uri so it looks like backend expects?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding parameters with [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) before passing to axios might solve your issue.

If you need to pass parameters with special characters (like '[',']' ...etc) you should give the parameter as a string '["junior","mid"]' instead of giving parameter as an array.
(Giving as an array will just remove the brackets)

```
var params = '["junior","mid"]'
encodeURI(params) // it returns "%5B%22junior%22,%22mid%22%5D"

var params = ["junior","mid"]
encodeURI(params) // it returns "junior,mid"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure if it solves my problem. If my uri was %5B%22junior%22,%22mid%22%5D it won't work. Also, I still don't know how I can put object keys and values to uri, separate it by comma and add apostrophe when it's needed.